# What is this pin?

Tags: identification, jewelry

This was my grandmother’s pin. She was born in 1905 and educated in Alabama. Graduated from Judson college with a degree in violin.

Small black diamond shaped lapel pin with two gold stars.

[image]

Comment: [Googleimage search](https://lens.google.com/search?p=AXAp4whkrxiyZLpqYWRH2WKWF7O8sMmQ1dZzN_MxZrzWKekAT0TggAJMTkRcStoKuSvTdRK_KGXFSmUcQiIluyva5p2yAYn7hp8yWjIJqH4Xg_wA3xtyNphDfZe3hLtUH3ru1jL4wyMhSzFNcbTTqEtlv-2dNLlPIT3I0myqI0wBhedzoAxLwxKJkzWiWJ6dOQSlG4vno4B9pMGtpkdFaNaZ_g9wPun0ztaHOfCqgXZqLbtQGBsfnhu5&ep=gisbubu&hl=en&re=df#lns) says [Alpha Delta Pi](https://www.hjgreek.com/product/showProduct/OrganizationCategoryID/2071/productID/62753). Apparently your mom was in a sorority

Comment: Thank you so much. She was an Alpha delta Pi. I have her actual pin. Perhaps this is a pledge pin or another honorary within the sorority. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh I see your link now. Alumni recognition. Again. Thank you.

Comment: @MCW: You should post that as an answer :)

Comment: @V2Blast - Justcal beat me to it FGITW.... So long as RuthBean gets an answer, life is god.

Answer (score 13):

Seems quite similar to a pin for sale [here](https://www.hjgreek.com/product/showProduct/OrganizationCategoryID/2071/productID/62753) which is listed as an '**ALUMNAE RECOGNITION PIN**', so it would be related to your grandmothers college time.